# python requests does not POST after redirect

Tags: python, python-requests

For some reason python requests does not do rePOST after encountered redirect header

```
import requests

proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888',}
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    r = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers, timeout=timeout, proxies=proxies, allow_redirects=True,)
    html = r.text
```

So it means I can't login to any form that is behind redirect. How can I solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: When following a redirect a browser is usually supposed to do a GET. It shouldn't rePOST unless it gets a 307 redirect. What redirect code is your server sending? You can work around this by setting `allow_redirects=False` and following the redirect in your own code.

Comment: @Duncan, on status_code I've 301. By the workaround you mean that I must double my requests to server? But under what condition the second requests should be added?

Comment: Normally a lot of websites do 301 directly after successfully logged in, this shouldn't be a problem for `requests`, would you mind specifying the website you're working one?

Comment: I can't share the link its private web-site, but in Fiddler4 I see 301 redirect to get and requests does not reposting anything. So I am looking any workaround.

Comment: Yes, if a POST gets a 301 redirect then the browser MUST redirect to a GET request. That's the rules, so if your server expects anything else it is broken and won't work with any browser.

Comment: That's not server issue. It redirects to get. But login form still there. Now I just making 2 requests and getting r.url from the first one, but is this only way to deal with it?

Comment: if login form is still there then you are not login. You have to use one request to login and later next request to POST data. You may have to use `requests.Session()` to keep and resend all cookies which inform server that you are login. BTW: evry page is different so there is no single solution for evry page.

Comment: @furas, so what's general solution? Make two requests?